# Why is this code in my shopify theme file?

Tags: shopify

I noticed these few lines of code which all mentioned IE9 (which I'm assuming no one is using for the most part).

```
  <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><script src="{{ 'lazysizes.min.js' | asset_url }}" async="async"></script><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="{{ 'lazysizes.min.js' | asset_url }}"></script><![endif]-->

  {% if template.directory == 'customers' %}
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><script src="{{ 'shopify_common.js' | shopify_asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script><!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="{{ 'shopify_common.js' | shopify_asset_url }}"></script><![endif]-->
  {% endif %}

  <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><script src="{{ 'vendor.js' | asset_url }}"></script><!--<![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="{{ 'vendor.js' | asset_url }}"></script><![endif]-->
```

Would this code be considered obsolete?

Comment: Reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Comment: Depending on whose numbers you believe, usage of all versions of IE has dropped below 4% ([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers)). Is that obsolete? You decide. Do you want to risk removing code you may not fully understand from your Shopify theme? Again, you decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove support for IE 9 or earlier version, you can remove the `if let IE 9` part, but the other one

```
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
```

This is for non-IE browsers and IE 9 above browsers, which I think you should keep.

> The extra "<!" is ignored by non-IE browsers; it is also ignored by IE regardless of the condition because if false, everything within the conditional comment is ignored, and if true, the resulting tag <!--> is unrecognized and therefore ignored.

More readings on this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment